# Query WP ACF Schema for a module

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm doing a custom Taxonomy override with ACF so that it can be updated easily by non-devs, as well be on any part of content we need it to (including LMS, Events, custom post types, etc) easily. But, I also want to query the "schema" of this module to grab the lists and build front-end filtering systems. What's the global place to grab such thing without relying on the post meta???

Comment: By "custom Taxonomy override with ACF", do you mean you have a fixed taxonomy slug and you are allowing people to customize the labels for it?

Comment: Or are you talking about individual terms within a given taxonomy?

Comment: It's just a different way to control taxonomy.

Created a module "group" in ACF that can be appended to any content type we choose that is nothing more than checkbox lists.

How can I pull what "lists" are available, the same as how the CMS page would display them

Comment: ACF being Advanced Custom Fields if that wasn't clear

Comment: So when you say Taxonomy, you don't mean a true WP taxonomy? Instead, you just mean an ACF field group with one or more fields? I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's just a field group. Inside the field group is 5 lists of "checkbox" type.

That's all. I just wanna know how to easily query that on the "Schema level" so I can build a UI from it on the front-end similar to how ACF builds it on the CMS

Comment: I've ended up just putting the module on an options page and querying that instead...